# update multiple row at once in two table

Tags: php, mysql, updates

I am sending multiple row of data at once by using post method,record of one table1 is updated because i am sending single row at once.But i am sending multiple row of data for table2 it is not updated my code is shown below:-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $serCount = count($_POST["user_id"]);
    //print_r($serCount);exit;  
   mysql_query("UPDATE users set user_name='".$_POST["user_name"]."',
   user_email='".$_POST["user_email"]."' WHERE id='".$_POST["user_id"][0]."'");
   for($i=0;$i<$serCount;$i++) {
       $sql1="UPDATE user_services set notification_date='".$_POST["notification_date"][$i]."',
      expiry_date='".$_POST["expiry_date"][$i]."',type ='".$_POST["type"][$i]."' 
      WHERE service_id='".$_POST["service_id"][$i]."'";
    //print_r($sql1);exit;
    }
//print_r($_POST);exit;
```

}
?>

Please suggest me whats the problem.

Comment: Does your form element is named like user_id[] ? Its important if you send several items via post with same name, to be defined more like an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking wrong count.

Use`count ($_POST['service_id']);`